# add custom attribute to createdElement - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using `createElement` to replace it with appending big chunk of html code. I understand I can add id, class, style easily with:

```
var container = 'container';

container.className = 'item';
container.style.cssText = 'color: red';
```

However, how can I add sub-id using this approach?

```
<div class="container">
    <i class="item" sub-id="item-19"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: why you tagged jquery while you just use pure javascript? anyway in jquery  just use  $('i.item').attr('sub-id','item-19');

Comment: Try `container.setAttribute("sub-id", "item-19")`. Documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and many other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
var container = $('<div />').attr('class','container');
var subId = $('<i />').attr({ 'class':'item', 'sub-id':'item-19'}).text('italic');

//append it to the body

$('body').append(container.append(subId));
```

Using the createElement methods would be more time consuming to program (but should be faster than jQuery). As for using the sub id in your createElement methods take a look at the API for an [Element Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

```
container.setAttribute("sub-id", "item-19");
```